# What do I do when "ait" fails me?

Tags: conjugation, infinitive

[In a separate answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/11045/406), I was trying to use *ait* in an English sentence:

> If the Lex Julia can *ait* its wording…

…but I ran into a problem. Even ignoring my bastard mixture of English and Latin, "can *ait*" sounds deeply wrong to me, just like **potest ait*; an infinitive would be better.

*Ait*, however, **doesn't seem to have any sort of infinitive**.

What should I do in cases like this, where an infinitive is grammatically needed? For example, *possum negāre* = "I am able to deny this"; how would I say the opposite, "I am able to *affirm* this", in natural-sounding Latin?

Comment: Indeed, building a "regular" infinitive (aiere?) seems unidiomatic. Why not _dicere_ or _affirmare_? In this context they sound perfectly well to me.

Comment: @Rafael Is it known which verb the Romans usually suppleted for this? If so that would make a good answer!

Comment: The classics are not my forte, but the exact phrase [_dicere licet_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&all_words=&phrase=dicere+licet&any_words=&exclude_words=&documents=) gives 12 hits, and [_dicere potest_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&all_words=&phrase=dicere+potest&any_words=&exclude_words=&documents=), 9. It is idiomatic; I'm afraid this doesn't answer the _suppleting_ issue, though.